# Sharepoint "Export to Spreadsheet" Question

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-excel

I have just begun programming in VBA and despite my researching efforts have a quick question for the community...

Is it possible to perform the sharepoint action "Export to Spreadsheet" using a VBA macro?

I want to export to excel and create a few pivot tables if you are wondering where I am going with this.

A push in the right direction would be extremely helpful... I wish I had some code to post but I am still in the planning/researching stage.

Comment: Export what from where?  What environment are you writing your VBA in?

Comment: I apologize for being vague. I have a List on a sharepoint site that I would like to export to Excel. I can manually do this by selecting "Action -> Export to Spreadsheet" and wanted to know if there was a way to automate the process. The manual process is described here: [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-a-sharepoint-list-to-a-spreadsheet-HA001119639.aspx)

Comment: You want to automate this from Excel?

Comment: That is my idea... To have a VBA macro that first gathers the data and then manipulates it (i.e. create pivot tables, etc) for reporting.

Comment: Maybe some code here which would help get you started: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exceldev/thread/62dfcd4f-0399-4be9-9da1-530d27ee611b

Comment: ...or here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930006

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and for your help... I will take a look at those shortly and see what I can do! I'm not completely sure if this is even possible. I'll update the thread if and when I make some progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first like to thank @Tim Williams for directing me towards the [support.microsoft.com/kb/930006](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930006) link as I believe I have found a solution to my question. (If I had enough reputation your comments would be upvoted!)

I was able to generate an .iqy file from the "Export to Spreadsheet" command which I have successfully transferred into a VBA web query. Alternatively, I was able to simply save the .iqy file and open it with the VBA code. Both have successfully populated my spreadsheet so I can now do the reporting I was looking to do.